# Variable fps (frame per second) in cv2

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, computer-vision, video-processing

I use `cv2` for creating videos from different frames that I have. When I create the video, I cannot change the fps (frame per second). I want the video be slow at the beginning but fast towards the end, meaning small fps at the beginning but large ones towards the end. However, when I instantiate `cv2.VideoWriter` I cannot change the fps anymore. What should I do?

**Replicable code**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, os
import matplotlib

image_size = 200
def create_image_array(image_size):
  image_array = np.random.randn(image_size, image_size)
  row = np.random.randint(0, image_size)
  image_array[row, :] = 100
  return image_array

frame_numbers = 200
for i in range(frame_numbers):
  image_array = create_image_array(image_size)
  matplotlib.image.imsave(f'./shots/frame_{i:03d}.png', image_array)

def make_a_video(shots_folder, video_path):

    shots_folder = 'shots'
    fps = 25
    images = [img for img in os.listdir(shots_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]

    images = sorted(images)[:]
    frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(shots_folder, images[0]))
    height, width, layers = frame.shape

    video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_path, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (width, height))

    for image in images:
        video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(shots_folder, image)))

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video.release()

shots_folder = 'shots'
video_path = 'video.mp4'  
make_a_video(shots_folder, video_path)
```

Comment: I am no expert on this but I don't think it's possible directly with OpenCV VideoReader. I think that just gives you the next frame and that's it. Same with VideoWriter. I think you can *maybe* process your video on a frame-by-frame basis with OpenCV, but in post-production cooy forward the PTS from the original video to the new. This might get you started https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/404761-Using-FFMPEG-to-copy-PTS-from-one-video-to-another-video-is-this-possible

Comment: @Mark Setchell: what is I create multiple videos with different frame per seconds and then stick them together. I do not know how I can attach videos together. I you can help me we that I am done.

Comment: I guess that may be possible, probably with `ffmpeg`, but I'm no expert. Maybe add the `ffmpeg` tag to your question to attract the right folks.

Comment: OpenCV can't do "variable frame rate". use PyAV and the custom PTS example. this is asked frequently on stack overflow.

Comment: this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847796/saving-numpy-array-as-video-relative-to-a-time-array/73848376#73848376 (not the other one I flagged to be the duplicate, too hastily)

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz: I do not want to do it by `PyAV`, they are not as fast as `cv2`.

Comment: If `cv2` can't do it, `pyav` would be infinitely faster if you ask me... but nonetheless, do you want to create a vfr video or to create a cfr video with vfr input frames?

Comment: @kesh: the jargons you use, I am not familiar with. Would it be possible for you to modify my code and do it with `pyav`. I mean translating my code to `pyav`. Then I can time both snippet and see if it is really faster. I am open to new tools.

Comment: If that's the case, cfr (constant framerate) video is what you're likely intended to create. All you need to do is then if the beginning is x1/2 speed then add the frame twice. (This is what FFmpeg would do.)

Comment: "not as fast" is *wrong*. OpenCV also just uses ffmpeg. OpenCV's use of ffmpeg _very recently_ gained some hardware acceleration but I think that only applies to decoding so far (can be wrong on that). anyway, PyAV gives you direct access to ffmpeg's libraries, so you can do _EVERYTHING_ that OpenCV does. -- @kesh no that is *not* what ffmpeg would do. ffmpeg is perfectly capable of working with Presentation Timestamps and requires no fixed frame rate or duplication *hacks*

Comment: BTW, the bottleneck in your code right now is `imsave`->`imread`. You should be able to feed numpy array straight to the writer (not 100% for `opencv` but should be possible)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - I know it can but it's default behavior is exactly that, isn't it? I wasn't aware that cfr vsync mode does interpolation. I'd stand corrected if that's the case. Btw, there is nothing "hack" about frame duplication. It's called nearest neighbor interpolation...

Comment: @kesh: "if the beginning is x1/2 speed", it is not. I want to have the variable fps not half exactly. I will think about your proposed method.

Comment: @kesh: I "the bottleneck in your code right now is `imsave->imread`". How can I fix it? How can I directly pass the array to the video because I create them on the fly?

Comment: "variable fps not half exactly" > right, whatever you want to do, you need to define a concrete relationship between the frame index and the frame time in seconds. There is no indication of such on your post

Comment: I don't know `opencv` but you should be able to use `rawvideo` format with `rgb24` `pix_fmt`. If you can configure your writer to take data in that way, you can pass the numpy array as is (assuming the array's `dtype` is in `uint8`)

Comment: The other commonly used alternative is to insert the same frame multiple times.  With any MPEG-based encoding, that will take up virtually no space in the output stream, and effectively reduces the frame rate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of it as if you are copying one video to another. While doing this you actually don't want to change the output frame rate but the input frame rate. Here is a very basic example of how you can continuesly change the read frame rate while you are writing a stream of constant frame rate.

The example generates a sample video of 200 frames and writes a video of 320 frames. The first 100 frames are read with 5 fps, the next 100 frames are read with an increasing rate from 5 to 25 fps and the last 120 frames are read with 25 fps.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2

image_size = 200
src_fps = 25
dst_fps = 25


# create sample frame with four rotating balls
def create_sample_frame(size, frame_no, fps):
    img = np.zeros((size, size, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    ctr = size // 2

    for i in range(1, 5):
        phi = -frame_no / fps * i
        r = size * (0.5 - 0.1 * i)
        cv2.circle(img, (round(math.sin(phi) * r + ctr), round(math.cos(phi) * r + ctr)), size // 30, (0, 255, 0), -1)

    return img


frames = [create_sample_frame(image_size, i, src_fps) for i in range(200)]
height, width, layers = frames[0].shape
video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), dst_fps, (width, height))

# ramp array with number of destination frames, start fps of source, end fps of source
fps_ramp = [[100, 5, 5], [100, 5, 25], [120, 25, 25]]

src_pos = 0
dst_pos = 0

for n, start_src_fps, end_src_fps in fps_ramp:
    for i in range(n):
        print(f"writing source frame {int(src_pos)} to destination frame {dst_pos}")
        video.write(frames[round(src_pos)])
        dst_pos += 1
        cur_fps = (end_src_fps - start_src_fps) * (i / n) + start_src_fps
        src_pos += cur_fps / src_fps

video.release()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: beautiful!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your problem. @Markus answer is correct for variable FPS. I saw you asked

> How can I directly pass the array to the video because I create them on the fly?

and as you said

> Please use the replicable code

I think you had trouble with applying Markus answer for your case.
maybe this is the code you're looking for

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

image_size = 200
src_fps = 25
dst_fps = 25


def create_image_array(image_size):
  image_array = np.random.randn(image_size, image_size, 3) * 255
  image_array = image_array.astype(np.uint8)
  row = np.random.randint(0, image_size)
  image_array[row, :] = 100

  if len(image_array.shape) == 2:
    image_array = cv2.cvtColor(image_array,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
  return image_array


frames = [create_image_array(image_size) for i in range(200)]

height, width, layers = frames[0].shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), dst_fps, (width, height))

# ramp array with number of destination frames, start fps of source, end fps of source
fps_ramp = [[100, 5, 5], [100, 5, 25], [120, 25, 25]]

src_pos = 0
dst_pos = 0

for n, start_src_fps, end_src_fps in fps_ramp:
    for i in range(n):
        print(f"writing source frame {int(src_pos)} to destination frame {dst_pos}")
        video.write(frames[round(src_pos)])
        dst_pos += 1
        cur_fps = (end_src_fps - start_src_fps) * (i / n) + start_src_fps
        src_pos += cur_fps / src_fps

video.release()
```

this code generates a colorful video **(I couldn't upload GIF because of StackOverflow upload limits)**

[image]

if you want grayscale, change `image_array = np.random.randn(image_size, image_size, 3) * 255` to `image_array = np.random.randn(image_size, image_size) * 255`

[image]